# Assertion error with uppercase / lower case not working (Python)

Tags: python, assertion, uppercase, lowercase

I've been studying the Python textbook  "Automate the boring stuff" and doing fine but this task has really stumped me. Been trying to do it for days, but can't get it right. Worst part is, I'm sure it's something kinda simple. What would you consider the best answer? Thank you.

*Write an assert statement that triggers an AssertionError if the variables
eggs and bacon contain strings that are the same as each other, even if
their cases are different (that is, 'hello' and 'hello' are considered the
same, and 'goodbye' and 'GOODbye' are also considered the same).*

Comment: Convert input string to lowercase and assert that both the input and the converted strings are equal. If the input had capital letters an AssertionError will be raised.

Comment: Unicode compare is something of dark art. What happens when a character has only one of the lower/upper case forms? This is worked out in `str.casefold`. So, `assert mystring1.casefold() != mystring2.casefold(), "Strings not the same"`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
assert eggs.lower() != bacon.lower()
```

Comment: lower and upper are unreliable across the unicode dataset. `str.casefold` does the job.